# string s = "hello" vs string s[5] = {"hello"}

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s = "hello";
  reverse(begin(s), end(s));
  cout << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**prints `olleh`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s[5] = {"hello"};
  reverse(begin(s), end(s));
  cout << *s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**prints `hello`**

Please help me understand why is such difference. I am newbie in c++, I am using c++ 11.
Ok, I corrected to s[5]={"hello"} from s[5]="hello" .

Comment: Your second example doesn't compile using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Because you are doing different things. In the second example you are using an array of strings not a single string. reverse in the second example reverses the array not a single string.

Comment: The second example is also invalid C++, what are you using? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baf5bc71d01b3365

Comment: @MarcoA. but as I mentioned already, it prints "hello" on console. btw what do you mean by invalid c++ ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a single string. The second is an array of five strings, and initializes all five string to the same value. However, allowing the syntax in the question is a bug (see the link in the comment by T.C.) and should normally give an error. The correct syntax would have the string inside braces, e.g. `{ "hello" }`.

In the second program you are only printing one string of the five anyway, the first one. When you dereference an array, it decays to a pointer and gives you the value that pointer points to, which is the first element in the array. `*s` and `s[0]` are equivalent.

Comment: Interestingly, the second one compiles with gcc, initializing 5 strings. See http://ideone.com/bxT5LL.

Comment: Yes, sure, but I can't figure out why that happens. I thought a brace enclosed initializer list would be needed.

Comment: thanks @Pileborg, but what is ** string s[5] = "hello" **  doing?? Shouldn't it be ** string s[5] = {"hello"} ** in second case. Since I have written "hello" without braces, it should raise error or something.

Comment: @featuresky Yes the braces should be needed, but apparently some compilers may have bugs allowing this (see e.g. the link from T.C.)

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you are looking for is this:

```
int main() {
  char s[] = "hello";
  reverse(s, s + (sizeof(s) - 1));
  cout << string(s) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

With `char[6]` you have an C-style string. Remember that theses strings must be terminated with `'\0'`. Therefore there is a 6th element.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure OP wants to use a C-style string. 2. Remove that `6`. 3. Change that `5` to `sizeof(s)-1`.

Comment: Item 2 is correct. Thanks. I'll change that. As for item 3: The second iterator marks just the end and is not edited, so it must be sizeof(s).

Comment: @flaviussixtus, No, I was talking about string class of c++ not C-style strings.

Comment: I can't figure out why this is up-voted. 1. It serves no purpose. 2. It is wrong. Did you even try it out?

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure about `sizeof(s)`. You might be "reversing" the null-character as well (i.e., placing it first).

Comment: @juanchopanza: I recommended `sizeof(s)-1` (equivalent to `strlen(s)`), but this user insisted on `sizeof(s)`...

Comment: @barakmanos: You are right. sizeof(s) - 1 is correct. I'll change that.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It served the purpose to find out if feature sky meant c-style strings. And wether you like it or not it did clarify that point. And that is probably the reason why it was upvoted.